# Delete resource images from drawable folder (hdpi) programmatically

Tags: android, image, drawable, android-sdcard

I am developing an app that does not use network. I am using a lot of images in it and want to store them on the sd card. How should I do it? Currently I an storing them in resource drawable hdpi folder. Is there a way to delete them programatically once the apk is installed? Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to delete the resources after installation instead you can remove from project itself. If your problem is move to sd card then change the preferred install location in manifest file.

Comment: I am planning to copy them on sd-card and then delete

Comment: The process of moving to sd card moves the resources to sd card .It is not possible to delete after moving to sd card.